# Sort view by tag count

Tags: views, 8, taxonomy-terms

I have to show all the tags and sort based on count. I am able to get the count of tag used by pages through views but not able sort based on count as this option is not available in views. Any suggestions?

Comment: Write a custom module?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible with just core views.

- Create a view that displays *terms*
- enable *aggregation*
- add relationship *Content with term*
- add sort *content uuid* with *aggregation type: count*
- add field *content uuid* with *aggregation type: count*
- add field *taxonomy term*

Your view should look similar to the following

[image]