# Show count in view grouping

Tags: views, 8

I'm building a index view to use as search. I'm grouping the results by a term field and everything works fine. What I want to do is add a count after the group title to show how many results that exists with this term.

Can't find a way to do this in drupal 8 so I'm asking you.
I've google for half a day without finding anything.

Answer (score 3):

Using [this answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/277887/sort-view-by-tag-count/277892#277892) as a base you can add [views_field_view](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_field_view) to include a view of content filtered by term.

In more details

## 1. Create a view of terms that includes count of content using each term

- Create a view that displays *terms*
- enable *aggregation*
- add relationship *Content with term*
- add sort *content uuid* with *aggregation type: count* (optional)
- add field *content uuid* with *aggregation type: count*
- add field *taxonomy term*

Your view should look similar to the following

[image]

## 2. Create a view that will display the content

- Include contextual filter on the vocabulary of your interest (*tags* in this case)
- Add any filters or fields that you need

This view will look similar to

[image]

## 3. Add last view as a field to first view (step 1.)

- Download and enable **views_field_view** module
- Go to view from step 1. and

  - add field *Taxonomy term: Term ID*
  - add field *Global view* ) (made available from *views_field_view*)
  - on the settings find the view from step 2.
  - use `{{ raw_fields.tid }}` as *contextual filter*

Next screenshot shows the changes from original view and settings for *view field*

[image]

**You are done**

Your view now should display the terms with count and all the content that have used it.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that it is a "Index" view, so the "Use aggregation" option is not available.